# DiscordJS Como faço quando ao finalizar um audio ele tocar outro

Tags: javascript, typescript

Minha duvida é seguinte, tenho um código que ele faz bot conectar ao canal de voz do discord quando usuário da comando "!!play url_video_youtube". Quando é digitado novamente comando é incrementado a array "listMusic". Minha duvida é como faço ao finalizar musica atual ele avança-se para próxima.

No "dispatcher.on('finish') consigo saber quando finalizou a musica, só não sei como faço pra tocar próxima musica de acordo com item da array.

```
async onPlayMusic (message:Message, url:string){
    listMusic.push(url);

    const voiceChannel = message?.member?.voice.channel;

        if (!voiceChannel) {
            return message.reply('precisa está em canal de voz!');
    }
    
    [0,1]

    voiceChannel.join().then(connection => {
            const stream = ytdl(url, { filter: 'audioonly' });
            const dispatcher = connection.play(stream);

            dispatcher.on('finish', () => {
        
        let musics = listMusic.length;
        
        if(musics > 1){
          listMusic[listMusic.length-1];
        }
        //voiceChannel.leave()
      });
    });
  },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basicamente você tem que criar um *loop* que verifica quantos links há em seu *array*, e que quando terminar de reproduzir ele passe para o próximo item do *array*.
Seria algo mais ou menos assim:

```
let url = ["www.musica.com", "www.proxima-musica.com"];// não sei como você cria o array com os link de reprodução, mas deve ficar asim imagino.
let index = 0;

function playMusic()//crisse uma função para que seja chamada novamente dentro de "on.finish"
{
    if ( url.length >= index )
    {
        voiceChannel.join().then(connection => 
        {   
            const stream = ytdl(url[index], { filter: 'audioonly' });
            const dispatcher = connection.play(stream);

            dispatcher.on('finish', () => 
            {
                let musics = listMusic.length;
                
                if(musics > 1)
                {
                  listMusic[listMusic.length-1];
                }

                index++//quando terminar de reproduzir ele acrecentar +1 no index;
                playMusic();//callback, que força um loop
            });
        });
    }else{
        //não á mais links no array para serem reproduzidas.
    }
}
```

Comment: Obrigado. Vou da uma estuda em callback achei bem interessante.